# Azure Data Studio Profiler doesn't show DBNames and LoginNames

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am using Azure Data Studio-Profiler to get all the events triggered by the users in my organisation, but I am unable to see the Login Name and Data Base Name those fields are populating empty.
Can anyone help me is there any setting or any query to run so that I can get those, or any other application to get all the events run by users in the organisation.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, This extension is actually for SQL Server and it is using Xevent to collect query execution details. And SQL Azure is different with SQL Server and we are only able to collect database level Xevent, so some of the fields shown in the tool actually does not exist in the collected XEvent files. So If want to review the user name for the query execution, we can use below  query in SSMS  to check the Xevent log of session [your session naem] and review it manually.

Script :

```
DECLARE @x XML;
SELECT @x = CAST(st.target_data AS XML)
FROM sys.dm_xe_database_sessions AS se INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_database_session_targets AS st ON se.address like st.event_session_address
where se.name = 'ADS_Standard_Azure'
select @x
```

Besides please note that as the Xevent session is saved to the memory with limited size,  we may lose the older events and also lose the history after database restart. So if want to track the login information of each query execution, actually we suggest using the Auditing feature of Azure SQL database. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing